# SEO: h1 with text vs. h1 with bg image and hidden text

Tags: seo, text, hidden-text

Having an h1 with "real" text in it is just as good for SEO as having that h1 with an image background and the same text, but set to be indented to -9999px and ltr?

Comment: Why did you move it here? I was a stackoverflow text-book question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the most part, the search engines only look at text.  Some of them do look at the CSS to see if the text is visible (either by `display: none` or background color ~ foreground color) so it is possible they will notice the `-9999px` and mark you down, but since it's a common technique it's unlikely.

In both approaches your code will look the same: `<h1>My SEo Website</h1>` The only difference should be your CSS.  You must still use text for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Yup, the markup will look exactly the same. And yes setting negative indentation is common, I do hope search engines look to see if negative indenting goes with background image and thus doesn't penalize the page. Thank you.